# Change IntelliJ code construct symbols

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a way to change the icons for [symbols](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/symbols.html) suchs the C for classes and the M methods. They're a little hard to distinguish on my laptop. Ideally I'd like to change it throughout the IDE but fine if it's just for the project pane or auto complete.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this can be done from the UI... All icons seems to be in `$IDEA_HOME/lib/icons.jar`. I guess you could copy this archive, unzip it, change the icons as you like and create JAR from it again. However it is possible that such changes might be overwritten when you update IDEA. I don't know much about making plugins for IntelliJ but one solution to this would be to wrap it in a plugin. Hope this gives you some pointers to a possible solution

Comment: Thank you so much for that @BohuslavBurghardt! The icons I'm after appear to be in `icons.jar/nodes/`. There appears to be a [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7285?pr=androidstudio) for Android Studio (the variant of IntelliJ I am using) which seems to have all the contents to its own set of icons -- I shall explore this further. In the meantime I think you should convert your comment to answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icons can't be changed via the UI as far as I know. It is however possible to change them manually. All icons used by IntelliJ are located in `$IDEA_HOME/lib/icons.jar`, where `$IDEA_HOME` represents the IntelliJ installation directory.

It might be possible to modify content of this JAR (by unzipping it, changing the icons and creating JAR from it again) and replace the original `icons.jar` with it. But change such as this will probably be overwritten during IntelliJ upgrade.

One solution would be to package the icons into a plugin. There is a [Idea 11 Icon Pack](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7285) plugin which does exactly the same thing you want. It is a JAR with the same structure as the `icons.jar`. Except two things:

- It has plugin descriptor (`META-INF/plugin.xml`) in order for the JAR to be registered as plugin
- It has implementation class `com/bulenkov/idea/Idea11IconPack` in order to register the icons I guess

I would use this as an inspiration. You can modify the descriptor so that there are no clashes in plugins, and change all of the old icons for your modified ones. One thing I'm not sure about is the implementation class. You could keep it and it might work. Or you could decompile it to see what it does and create your own version.

You can then install the JAR with the plugin descriptor by clicking *Install plugin from disk* button in the plugin settings.

Here is also a [documentation for plugin development](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+Plugin+Structure) which might be useful.

Comment: wow thanks for the extra tip on `META-INF/plugin.xml`, would +10 if I could!

Comment: @jay :) glad I could help. Let me know in the comments if this approach works for you to create your own plugin. And if you find some new relevant information regarding this issue, feel free to update my answer :)